# Trying to send html email body in Outlook but it is broken if the body has the character "&". iOS,Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, outlook

I am trying to open the Html body via outlook URL but the body is broken if some special character is present on the body example: &nbsp,&,&amp etc.

So I have tried "stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters" but still no luck.

It is working if I replace the character "&" with "and", but we need to show "&" in the body.

below is my piece code:

```
     NSString *strTest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ms-outlook://compose?to=%@&subject=%@&body=%@", emailTo,emailSubject,emailBody];
     NSURL *openurlTest = [NSURL URLWithString:[strTest stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

     NSURL *openurl = [NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
     if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:openurlTest]) {
          if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:openurlTest]) {
            
               [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:openurlTest options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
          }
     }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of constructing the URL using string formatting, I'd recommend using `NSURLComponents` in conjunction with `NSURLQueryItem` which will "do the right thing" as far as proper encoding.

```
    NSString *sampleBody = @"Ampersand & and more reserved characters !*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]";
    NSURLComponents *components = [[NSURLComponents alloc] initWithString:@"ms-outlook://compose"];
    NSURLQueryItem *toItem = [[NSURLQueryItem alloc] initWithName:@"to" value:@"test@email.com"];
    NSURLQueryItem *subjectItem = [[NSURLQueryItem alloc] initWithName:@"subject" value:@"Test Subject"];
    NSURLQueryItem *bodyItem = [[NSURLQueryItem alloc] initWithName:@"body" value:sampleBody];
    components.queryItems = @[toItem, subjectItem, bodyItem];
    NSLog(@"Constructed URL = %@", [components.URL absoluteString]);
```

Which outputs:

```
ms-outlook://compose?to=test@email.com&subject=Test%20Subject&body=Ampersand%20%26%20and%20more%20reserved%20characters%20!*'();:@%26%3D+$,/?%25%23%5B%5D
```

NSURLComponents: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlcomponents?language=objc

NSURLQueryItem: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlqueryitem?language=objc

NSURLComponents.queryItems: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlqueryitem?language=objc

NSURLComponents queryItems header:

> // The query component as an array of NSURLQueryItems for this NSURLComponents.
> //
> // Each NSURLQueryItem represents a single key-value pair,
> //
> // Note that a name may appear more than once in a single query string, so the name values are not guaranteed to be unique. If the NSURLComponents has an empty query component, returns an empty array. If the NSURLComponents has no query component, returns nil.
> //
> // The queryItems getter returns an array of NSURLQueryItems in the order in which they appear in the original query string. Any percent-encoding in a NSURLQueryItem name or value is removed.
> //
> // The queryItems setter combines an array containing any number of NSURLQueryItems, each of which represents a single key-value pair, into a query string and sets the NSURLComponents query property. If the NSURLQueryItems name or value strings contain any characters not allowed in a URL's query component, those characters are percent-encoded. In addition, any '&' and '=' characters in a NSURLQueryItem name are percent-encoded. Passing an empty array sets the query component of the NSURLComponents to an empty string. Passing nil removes the query component of the NSURLComponents.
> //
> // - note: If a NSURLQueryItem name-value pair is empty (i.e. the query string starts with '&', ends with '&', or has "&&" within it), you get a NSURLQueryItem with a zero-length name and a nil value. If a NSURLQueryItem name-value pair has nothing before the equals sign, you get a zero-length name. If a NSURLQueryItem name-value pair has nothing after the equals sign, you get a zero-length value. If a NSURLQueryItem name-value pair has no equals sign, the NSURLQueryItem name-value pair string is the name and you get a nil value.

Specifically this portion of the header is of interest for your question:

> If the NSURLQueryItems name or value strings contain any characters not allowed in a URL's query component, those characters are percent-encoded. In addition, any '&' and '=' characters in a NSURLQueryItem name are percent-encoded.